# How can i journal all my tables's schema in db2 iseries as/400?

Tags: db2, journal, iseries-navigator

I  have created using system i navigator a jounral called abc in schema called TEST.Now i want to journal all the tables in my schema called mySchema how can i do that.I can only journal only one table.Is there any script to journal all the tables at once.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Find your journal then right click on it.

[image: Right click menu]

Choose start or end table journaling. You'll get this screen:

[image: Start/End Table Journaling]

Find and add your tables. I believe you can Ctrl or Shift- click multiple tables at once.

Comment: unfortunately you can't make multiple selection.Which version do you use Mike? i have tried ctrl and shift click but in vain

Comment: Sorry, I am having other problems trying it out. It was quite a while ago when I tried it so my memory could be incorrect. I thought for sure that the standard shift-click and ctrl-click functionality worked though.

Comment: I am clueless on Journaling. <-- so cluless I can't even spell it right according to browser auto correct. But I need it for transactions to an as400 database. To Journal a table, do you have to define a Journal? Or do you just have to define the table as Journal.. thanks!

Comment: You need to select tables one by one. There is not shift-click or ctrl-click. Any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

If you created a "schema" with iSeries Navigator, then a journal will be created in the schema automatically and all tables created in that schema will be journaled automatically. Automatic journaling can also be set up for simple "libraries", in case you created a "library" rather than a "schema". See [**Automatically starting journaling**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzaki/rzakiautostrjrnl.htm) for details. (For i 6.1 and later, also look at the `STRJRNLIB` command.)